# Could not load document /LoW.xml. Maybe it is not valid TEI or not in the TEI namespace?

Tags: exist-db, tei

I am sure this is quite basic, but I'm putting together a traning-database with some files on the loss of a particular ship. 
When uploading it to exist-db (I created the DB with tei-publisher ...) and wanting to present the file, I get the above error.

I am quite sure that my file is okay, however, I am quite irritated.
Please find the tei-code in the following paste.

https://pastebin.com/0H3jCfe8
the header is in code, as required (and irritating)

```
    <teiHeader>
    <fileDesc>
        <titleStmt>
            <title>TITLE</title>
        </titleStmt>
        <editionStmt/>
        <extent/>
        <publicationStmt/>
        <seriesStmt/>
        <notesStmt/>
        <sourceDesc>Description</sourceDesc>
    </fileDesc>
    <revisionDesc/>
</teiHeader>
```

OxygenXML claims IllegalStateException but I cannot find the error....

Comment: furthermore, Oxygen claims that I miss an ending tag somewhere. In the aforementioned paste it claims that text is missing the end tag (or <pb> + I am not allowed to use <li></li> inside the <pb></pb>

Comment: There are a few issues here. (1) The oXygen "IllegalStateException" is likely caused by a bad path to a schema file, `../Downloads/tei_BOO(1).rng`. Could you confirm the intended file is at this path relative to the file? Just to troubleshoot, try deleting the `<?xml-model?>` processing instruction and validating. (2) Could you provide more information about the steps you use to upload and display this file via TEI Publisher? What is the location of your file in the database, and what is the URL that displays the "Could not load /LoW.xml" error? Please paste in the full error if there's more.

Comment: (3) Your text needs to be wrapped in a `<text>` tag (starting after the `<facsimile>` element. Also, `<pb>` is an empty element - used to mark the place where the new page begins; it may not contain any child text or elements. You'd typically place the text on a page in a `<div>` and then inside a `<p>` (or more generically an `<ab>`) tag.

Comment: So:     `<text>
        <body>
            <pb facs="Page1.jpg"/>
            <div>
                <p>At a Court-Martial held on board...</p> 
            </div>
        </body>
    </text>`

Comment: I am deleting this - not because you were not helpful / it was not insightful but because my machine crashed and I need to set it up again ( my phd-work is backed up, the database wasn't ... a mistake I am not going to make again! )

Comment: @joewiz: I think I used the wrong schema-format when validating the file, however I cannot be sure ... :-/ 
I need more knowledge about xml and the neighbboring technology!

Comment: Sorry to hear about the crash. Good luck!